# How could this Apache Tomcat code be simplified with a Monadic Bind?

Tags: java, haskell, bind, monads, nested-if

The [commentator writes](https://twitter.com/hackuador/status/679286796996374528):

> Some nice "greater-than sign" code in Tomcat.  Needs a healthy dose of (>>=).

When looking at [the AuthenticatorBase.java class from Apache Tomcat](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java):

```
/**
 * Enforce the security restrictions in the web application deployment
 * descriptor of our associated Context.
 *
 * @param request Request to be processed
 * @param response Response to be processed
 *
 * @exception IOException if an input/output error occurs
 * @exception ServletException if thrown by a processing element
 */
@Override
public void invoke(Request request, Response response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("Security checking request " +
            request.getMethod() + " " + request.getRequestURI());
    LoginConfig config = this.context.getLoginConfig();

    // Have we got a cached authenticated Principal to record?
    if (cache) {
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        if (principal == null) {
            Session session = request.getSessionInternal(false);
            if (session != null) {
                principal = session.getPrincipal();
                if (principal != null) {
                    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
                        log.debug("We have cached auth type " +
                            session.getAuthType() +
                            " for principal " +
                            session.getPrincipal());
                    request.setAuthType(session.getAuthType());
                    request.setUserPrincipal(principal);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have to admit, I'm missing how this could be applied. I get that there is potentially a way to refactor an if-tree to a monadic bind, but I don't see how to do it.

**Assumptions:**

- This is not about language, but about the logic construct. You could represent this if-tree in Haskell or Scala or Clojure and it would still be representing the same if-logic.

My question is: **How could this Apache Tomcat code be simplified with a Monadic Bind?**

Comment: This nice talk about "refactoring ruby with monads" covers the "removing duplication from error checking" case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1jYlPtkrqQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of the Twitter comment.  In this example the "low-hanging fruit" for
simplification, assuming the existence of a monadic *option type*, is the several layers of nested code predeciated on *"`foo` is not `null`"*.

Let us focus on the following snippet:

```
Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
if (principal == null) {
    Session session = request.getSessionInternal(false);
    if (session != null) {
        principal = session.getPrincipal();
        if (principal != null) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled())
                log.debug("We have cached auth type " +
                    session.getAuthType() +
                    " for principal " +
                    session.getPrincipal());
            request.setAuthType(session.getAuthType());
            request.setUserPrincipal(principal);
        }
    }
}
```

Since we are talking about general constructions rather Java specifically, or any particular language, let's introduce some new assumptions (which may or may not be easily embodied in Java code), and we will refactor the code to exploit them.

**Assumption 1**: all methods that could return `null` return an [`Optional<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) instead, and **never return `null`** because the absense/failure case is handled in the `Optional` value itself.  In other languages `Optional` is variously called `Option`, `Maybe` and possibly other names.

**Assumption 2**: `Optional` has a *monadic bind* method.  Java 8's `Optional` calls this function `flatMap`, so we will call it that as well.  In Haskell, it is called `>>=`, but the name does not matter - what matters is the type:

```
<U> Optional<U> flatMap(Function<? super T,Optional<U>> mapper)
```

For comparison, in Haskell `>>=` is defined for all types that have an instance of the `Monad` type class; the type signature being:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

When specialised to `Maybe` and using different type variable names, the correspondence to Java's `Optional` becomes clearer.

```
(>>=) :: Maybe t -> (t -> Maybe u) -> Maybe u
```

**Assumption 3**: the language has first-class lambdas.  I know that Java 8 has lambdas but I do not know the syntax of the top of my head, so I'm just going to make it up :)

Applying these assumptions, the **simplified code** looks something like:

```
Optional<Principal> principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
if (!principal.isPresent()) {
    Optional<Session> session = request.getSessionInternal(false);
    principal = session.flatMap((sess) { sess.getPrincipal() });
    principal.flatMap((principal) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) ... // as before
        request.setAuthType(session.getAuthType());
        request.setUserPrincipal(principal);
    })
}
```

Notice that each successive call to `flatMap` removes an `if` level from the program.  The calls to `flatMap` can also be chained to avoid intermediate assignments.

The benefits to using a monadic bind pattern in Java are apparent, but they are unfortunately limited.  Because `flatMap` is definined concretely for `Optional` (perhaps a similar method is also defined concretely for other types), rather than abstractly over a type class or interface, the programmer does not have access to the many derived operations for free.  Such derived operations must be manually written for each instance.

Comment: Haven't you failed to handle a null value in your second line?

Comment: No, for we assume that a function that returns `Optional<T>` *never* returns `null`.  The failure/absense case is handled in the `Optional` value.  I will clarify in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here you have side effects (`request.set...`), and bind is more useful when you don't. Using `ifPresent` is sufficient:

```
Optional.ofNullable(principal).ifPresent(principal ->
  Optional.ofNullable(request.getSessionInternal(false)).ifPresent(session ->
    Optional.ofNullable(session.getPrincipal).ifPresent(principal -> {
      if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug(...);
      request.setAuthType(session.getAuthType());
      request.setUserPrincipal(principal);
    })));
```

This may not look like a win; repeating but `Optional.ofNullable(...)` wouldn't be necessary if `request.getSessionInternal` and `session.getPrincipal` already returned `Optional`.

And you can write a method which works like `Optional.ofNullable(...).ifPresent`:

```
public static <T> void ifNotNull(T value, Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
  if (value != null) { consumer.accept(value); }
}

ifNotNull(principal, principal ->
  ifNotNull(request.getSessionInternal(false), session ->
    ifNotNull(session.getPrincipal, principal -> {
      if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug(...);
      request.setAuthType(session.getAuthType());
      request.setUserPrincipal(principal);
    })));
```

(Note: not sure I remember Java syntax exactly, I haven't used it for some time.)